# Trying to make an image classifier by using CNN's and pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create an image classifier that labels an image with the kind of food it is. I've got: 11 classes ('apple_pie', 'cheesecake', 'chicken_curry','french_fries','fried_rice','hamburger','hot_dog', 'ice_cream', 'omelette', 'pizza', 'sushi'), 1100 test images and 9900 train images.
I've never programmed inpython and this is my last programming subject.

I think I'm not creating the validation (val) folder righ but I'm not sure how to do it. My main directory is content/drive/MyDrive/TDI 2023/Deteccion_auto_comidas/ with a test folder and a train folder.
If someone could give me a hand I would extremely appreciate it.

```
%matplotlib inline
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torchvision import transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
import os
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch import nn
import torch.optim as optim



!KAGGLE_USERNAME="username" KAGGLE_KEY="mykey" kaggle competitions download -c deteccin-automtica-de-comidas-con-cnns
!unzip -n -qq deteccin-automtica-de-comidas-con-cnns.zip

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')


device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


root_train = '/content/drive/MyDrive/TDI 2023/Deteccion_auto_comidas/train/'
# Crear la lista de clases
classes = os.listdir(root_train)
# Crear un diccionario que asocie cada clase con su ruta
class_to_path = {}
for class_name in classes:
    class_path = os.path.join(root_train, class_name)
    class_to_path[class_name] = class_path 
# Crear una lista de rutas a las imágenes de todas las clases
image_paths = []
for class_name, class_path in class_to_path.items():
    image_filenames = os.listdir(class_path)
    class_image_paths = [os.path.join(class_path, image_filename) for image_filename in image_filenames]
    image_paths += class_image_paths
# ruta a la carpeta que contiene los datos de entrenamiento
#train_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/TDI 2023/Deteccion_auto_comidas/train/"

# ruta a la carpeta que contiene los datos de prueba
#test_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/TDI 2023/Deteccion_auto_comidas/test/"

# transformación de datos que se aplicará a cada imagen
train_transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224, 224)), transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])


!pip install split-folders
import splitfolders


input_folder = "/content/drive/MyDrive/TDI 2023/Deteccion_auto_comidas/"
output_folder = "/content/drive/MyDrive/TDI 2023/Deteccion_auto_comidas/val"

# Especifica la proporción para dividir tus datos
# en sets de train y validación
splitfolders.ratio(input_folder, output_folder, seed=42, ratio=(0.8, 0.2))

root_val = output_folder

class CustomTestDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_test, transform=None):
        self.root = root_test
        self.transform = transform
        self.images = []
        self.labels = []
        
        # Obtener la lista de archivos de imagen en la carpeta de prueba
        self.file_list = os.listdir(self.root)
        self.file_list = [f for f in self.file_list if f.endswith('.jpg') or f.endswith('.jpeg') or f.endswith('.png')]
        
        # Cargar las imágenes y etiquetas de prueba
        for filename in self.file_list:
            # La etiqueta es el nombre de la imagen sin la extensión
            label = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
            img = Image.open(os.path.join(self.root, filename)).convert('RGB')
            if self.transform is not None:
                img = self.transform(img)
            self.images.append(img)
            self.labels.append(label)
        print(f"Number of images: {len(self.images)}")
        print(f"Number of labels: {len(self.labels)}") #Deberían de tener la misma longitud

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img = self.images[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]
        return img, label

root_test = '/content/drive/MyDrive/TDI 2023/Deteccion_auto_comidas/test/'
test_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5])])
test_data = CustomTestDataset(root_test, transform=test_transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=32)

class CustomTrainDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset, transform=None):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.root = root_train
        self.transform = transform
        self.class_to_idx = {class_name: i for i, class_name in enumerate(os.listdir(os.path.join(root_train)))}
       

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image, label = self.dataset[index]
        label_idx = self.class_to_idx[label]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image, label

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)       

'''
dataset = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_train):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        if file_path.endswith(".jpg"):
            label = os.path.basename(subdir)
            image = Image.open(file_path)
            image_tensor = transform(image)
            dataset.append((image_tensor, label))
    break
    print(file_path)
print(dataset)
'''

class_names = ['apple_pie', 'cheesecake', 'chicken_curry','french_fries','fried_rice','hamburger','hot_dog', 'ice_cream', 'omelette', 'pizza', 'sushi']
class_indices = range(len(class_names))
class_to_idx = dict(zip(class_names, class_indices))
sorted_class_names = [class_names[idx] for idx in sorted(class_to_idx.values())]
print(sorted_class_names) #Debería imprimir el orden correcto de las clases

input_size = (3, 512, 512)
batch_size = 32

class FoodCNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_classes=11):
        super(FoodCNN, self).__init__()
      
        # Capa convolucional 1
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        # Capa convolucional 2
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        # Capa convolucional 3
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        # Capa totalmente conectada
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=64*24*24, out_features=512)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        
        # Capa de salida
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=num_classes)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.pool3(x)
        
        x = x.view(-1, 64*24*24)
        
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        
        x = self.fc2(x)
        
        return x


# Creamos las transformaciones de datos para los conjuntos de entrenamiento y validación
train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512, 512)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])
val_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512, 512)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

# Creamos los datasets de entrenamiento y validación
train_data = CustomTrainDataset(root_train, transform=train_transform)
val_data = CustomTrainDataset(root_val, transform=val_transform) #el set de validación ha sido creado a partir de las imágenes de train

# Creamos los dataloaders de entrenamiento y validación
train_data = CustomTrainDataset(root_train, transform=train_transform)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

#Creamos el modelo
model = FoodCNN(num_classes=11)
# Definir la función de pérdida y el optimizador
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

'''
def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # Compute prediction and loss
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")

def test_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    num_batches = len(dataloader)
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()

    test_loss /= num_batches
    correct /= size
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")
    '''

# Entrenar el modelo
for epoch in range(10):
    # Establecer el modelo en modo de entrenamiento
    model.train()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        # Mover los datos y las etiquetas al dispositivo (GPU o CPU)
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)

        # Restablecer los gradientes del optimizador
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Calcular las predicciones del modelo
        output = model(data)

        # Calcular la pérdida
        loss = loss_fn(output, target)

        # Retropropagar la pérdida y actualizar los pesos del modelo
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    # Evaluar el modelo en el conjunto de validación
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in val_dataloader:
            # Mover los datos y las etiquetas al dispositivo (GPU o CPU)
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)

            # Calcular las predicciones del modelo
            output = model(data)

            # Calcular la pérdida
            val_loss += loss_fn(output, target).item()

            # Obtener la clase predicha para cada imagen
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)

            # Calcular el número de predicciones correctas
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    # Calcular la precisión y la pérdida promedio en el conjunto de validación
    val_loss /= len(val_dataloader.dataset)
    val_acc = 100. * correct / len(val_dataloader.dataset)

    # Imprimir las métricas de entrenamiento y validación
    print('Epoch: {}, Train Loss: {:.4f}, Val Loss: {:.4f}, Val Acc: {:.2f}%'.format(
        epoch+1, loss.item(), val_loss, val_acc))

'''
epochs = 2
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train_loop(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    test_loop(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
print("Done!")
'''
```

I think I'm not creating the validation (val) folder correctly but I'm not sure how to do it. If someone could give me a hand I'd extremely appreciate it.